# Simple regex question to remove \

Tags: javascript, regex, asp-classic

I have a simple question how do I remove a `\` with regex?

Thanks

I have tried it like this `.replace(/\\/ig, '');`

I am using javascript and classic asp

Now it works: `.replace(/\\/ig, '');` somehow the first time I tried it, it were not working! - Thanks for all the quick answers!

Comment: In what context (language or environment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested out the following and it worked (in a [test bench](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace2)) on the first `\` (due to `"\\"`), but not the second `\` (because it was in a string, thus acting as an escape character).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="\\ \ ";
document.write(str.replace(/\\/ig,"replaced"));
</script>
```

Are you sure that the `\` you wish to replace is not just acting as an escape character and doesn't really exist in the output?

Comment: it is a physical path c:\www\ << needed to remove the slashes

Answer (score 0):

Double prefix with \ so become `\\`

Answer (score 0):

Why regular expressions? You don't need a [formal language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match a single character. It can be done with a simple string replace in your favorite language. Try `str_replace('\\', '', $string)` in PHP, or `myString.replace('\\', '')` in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

in python

```
re.sub(r'\\', '', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

in c# it would be something like

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\\");
string result = rgx.Replace(@"this backslash \  should go", "");
```

Comment: @freddoo close. You need to escape the backslashes, so there would be 4 of them: "\\\\". Otherwise use the verbatim string symbol by prefixing the string with an `@` symbol. I've edited to include this.